# Generating non-repeating numbers in rows & columns of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

Basically, I am trying to create a method that takes a 2 dimensional array as an argument, and returns 9 rows and 9 columns of random numbers from 1 to 9 (think Sudoku puzzle), where none of the numbers in the row can repeat, and also none of the numbers in the column can repeat.

I am almost there (I think), but I cannot get the numbers to not repeat in both the rows (east to west) and the columns (north to south).

Here is my code...

```
/**
 * This method generates a 9x9 2D array and randomly places numbers between 1 and 9 in each cell.
 * Each row containing numbers 1 through 9 should not have any repeating numbers going across.
 * Each column containing numbers 1 through 9 should not have any repeating numbers going down.
 * @param array the array that will be generated
 */
public static void generatePuzzle(int[][] array) {
    array =  new int[9][9]; //creates array of size N
    //generates random numbers 1 inclusive to # exclusive
    List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        randomList.add(i + 1);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(randomList);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            array[i][j] = randomList.get(j);
        }
        // Shuffle the list again to get different values for the next line
        Collections.shuffle(randomList);
        System.out.println(randomList);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for any pointers and help you can give!!

Comment: I dont see any attempt to filter out duplicates.... you are just adding elements, not checking for duplicates anywhere.

Comment: The reason you aren't getting any repeats for either rows or columns (not both) is that each number in the list is unique (and each index is only used once). One thing you can try is first creating the entire 2D array row by row (i.e. rows won't repeat), then checking for repeats column by column, reshuffling any row with a repeated column (continuing until this is no longer the case). Then, when there are finally no repeats, print out the 2D array. There may very well be a better way to do this though.

Comment: Instead of `randomList.get( j )` you want `randomList.remove( 0 )`.  And of course this leaves your randomlist empty, so in preparation for the next iteration you need to refill it with sequential values before shuffling it.

Comment: But this will not solve your problem.  The code that builds a sudoku is probably the most frequently occurring code sample of java out there in the great interwebz, why don't you google for it instead of asking here?

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh well yes, that is my question - I do not know how to go about checking for duplicates...

Monkeygrinder that is kinda what I am trying to do with this code, to no avail.

Mike Nakis you are correct in your statement, except the most common stuff out there that you are referring to is not quite what I am looking for. I've been through it all, but thanks tho!

Comment: Start things off simple. Try and get one column with no repeats (none of the rows should repeat). You can assume that the first row isn't repeated, and in the following rows, you can use a nested for-loop to check that column value against the column value in previous rows.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder I appreciate your help, and I've already done all that. It's something very small that I'm not catching. I'll figure it out at some point, cause if I don't see the code, I won't really know what you're referring to. Thanks a bunch for trying anyway!

Comment: If you've already done checks for duplicates, then you should edit your question to include those checks in the code block. A sample output might be good too. On an unrelated note, it might be helpful to replace int `i` and `j` with int `row` and `col`. @MikeNakis suggestion regarding remove() is also a good hint regarding efficiency. I may forget, but I'll try and check back here in a bit and if you're still looking for an answer, I can give you something (likely won't be the best way). For now though, sleep is what calls. Good luck.